# SQL запрос (пример)

Tags: sql

```
create table clients (customer_id int primary key serial, first_name varchar(30), last_name varchar(30), address varchar(30), zip_code varchar(10), country char(2), birthdate date, username varchar(15), password varchar(35));
```

В чем неправильность запроса? Хочу чтобы customer_id поле было первичным ключом(id) и чтобы там был autoincrement. В чем ошибка? Подскажите пожалуйста (PostgreSQL)

Comment: Какая СУБД хоть?

Comment: @andreymal postgresql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У тебя две спецификации типа.

Первая - тип INT.

Вторая - тип SERIAL (INT плюс автоинкремент).

Отсюда и ошибка синтаксиса.

Comment: спасибо большо!

Comment: А еще хотел спросить получается мы пишем допустим create table test2 (id serial primary key, name ...) и тд. Указываем что это первичный ключ и сериал (если нам нужен автоинкремент), да? Или как правильней?

Comment: @MikeMclaren Да, в PostgreSQL именно так. *как правильней?* Ну на любителя... хотя я бы рекомендовал отдельно создавать счётчик, и отдельным предложением создавал первичный ключ. Первое - в общем может быть важно, чтобы иметь возможность независимо управлять счётчиком по имени.

Comment: Как понять отдельно создавать счётчик и отдельным предложением создавать первичный ключ?

Comment: @MikeMclaren См. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL